When during the trip, we have to stay in a city for a night stop and continue the route tomorrow, what do we call that city? Stop or station?
In the past, travelers traveling to distant cities for business had to spend the night at rest stops along the way. Sometimes these resorts were a special building like a caravanserai, in which case we call it a station. But if we want to refer to the city where they stopped, as a point, can we still use the word station or is there a better word for it?

A place where travellers regularly stop on a long journey can be called a staging post.

A caravanserai is not a station at all.
A station is a place where scheduled services stop; usually trains, but also including buses and coaches. You wouldn't call a truckers' rest stop a station, for example. And you definitely wouldn't refer to a city as a station.

Of course, there are different types of caravanserais. Some of them even had a bakery and a grocery store like a small town. Others existed only as places to stop for the night without special amenities. I meant an intermediate place between these two types of caravanserais. But the main issue is how should I address this caravanserai and the small town where this caravanserai was located?
